# Graph like wolfram alpha using JQuery and img

Tags: jquery, html, graph, shared-libraries, wolframalpha

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#getIt').on('click', function () {

         });

});
```

I tried a lot of things but nothing work for me because I'm the new developer not easy for me so,
when I click on the button, I want to send text input to wolfram alpha or library file  that I didn't found in the web, and then I want to have a graph like wolfram alpha format to show at my img html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take value from textbox and pass it into image attribute like this, and then implement it on your wolfram alpha project.

**http://jsfiddle.net/x6HyZ/2/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     var myvalue = $("#textbox").val();
     $("img").attr("src",myvalue );
  });
});
```

Comment: you didn't answer my question

Comment: @TheMasterM3 no-one is here to do all your homework/job from scratch. You must try somethign and then come in here to fix the errors you have. My answer above will guide you how to start with it.